# Whether or not a measure is finite or $\sigma$-finite

Tags: integration, lebesgue-measure, borel-measures

I have been given the following question:

Let $\mu$ be a Borel measure on $[1, \infty)$ given by the density function 1/x with respect to the 1-dimensional Lebesgue measure. Is measure $\mu$ finite or $\sigma$-finite?

Since the outputs of the density function contains numbers within the rational numbers, which are countable, and furthermore of finite measure, I believe it fits the description of $\sigma$-finite, but I'm not sure?

Furthermore, I must consider a function $f : [1, \infty)→ \mathbb R$ such that $f(x)= e^{-x}cos(x)$. I need to find out whether or not the integral $∫_{[1, \infty)}fdμ$ exists, I don't have to evaluate it, but just give precise arguments.

I'm pretty sure the integral exists and is equal to 1/2, but I don't know how to give a more general proof, of how to show whether or not it exists :-)

Comment: 1. Can you break the domain $[1, \infty)$ into a countable number of disjoint subsets, each of which have finite measure under $\mu$? 2. Can you find $g(x) \geq 0$ such that $g(x)\,dx \geq f(x)\,d\mu$ but $\int_{x=1}^\infty g(x)\,dx$ is finite?

Comment: Good questions, the information provided above is all I've been given :-)

Comment: No, my questions are a program to arrive at an answer. :-)

Comment: It is $\sigma$ finite since $\int_{[a,b]}\frac1x\,dx=\log(b/a)<\infty$ and $[1,\infty)=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}[n,n+1]}$